# Response of webservice doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm using express and NodeJS. I created a helloworld webservice. 
I call this webservice in ReactJS with Axios.
But I have a problem with the response of Webservice
This my webservice :

```
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
const app = express()
const port = 4002
app.use(bodyParser())
app.use(busboy());
app.use('/', express.static('./'));   
app.get('/helloworld', (req, res) => {
   return res.send('hello world')
})
```

Here, I call the webservice :

```
callWs = () => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:4002/helloworld`)
        .then(response => {            
           console.log('WS') // it doesn't work
        }) .catch(function (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                console.log('Error data : ', error.response.data);
                console.log('Error status : ', error.response.status);
                console.log('Error headers : ', error.response.headers);
            } else if (error.request) {
                console.log('Error request : ', error.request);
            } else {
                console.log('Error message : ', error.message);
            }
            console.log(error.config);
        })                 
    }
```

And here, the console of navigator  : 
[image]

It just works with json data

Do you have an idea ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With the code you are showing, I find you are missing the port setting in the server:

```
app.listen(port);
```

Without it I am getting a ECONNREFUSED error.

If you add that and change the line in the function to this:

```
callWs = () => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:4002/helloworld`)
        .then(response => {            
           console.log(response.data)
        }) .catch(function (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                console.log('Error data : ', error.response.data);
                console.log('Error status : ', error.response.status);
                console.log('Error headers : ', error.response.headers);
            } else if (error.request) {
                console.log('Error request : ', error.request);
            } else {
                console.log('Error message : ', error.message);
            }
            console.log(error.config);
        })                 
    }
```

You properly receive the `hello world` message.

Comment: Thank you but it's the same thing :(

Answer (score 0):

1- You should launch express server by adding this line at the end:

```
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Express app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

2- You are serving [static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) from the root directory, you have to create a `public` folder and use it to render static files:

```
const path = require("path");
...
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

3- If you want to manage file upload use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) package instead of busboy

Finally your server side code should look like this:

```
const express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    port = 4002,
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    path = require("path");

// body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser());
// serving static files from ./public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/helloworld', (req, res) => {
    return res.send('hello world')
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Express app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've tested your solution, and it's the same thing.. the webservice is called, but I have the same error on the response

Comment: when you start the web service  with ` node app.js ` for example, does it shows something in the console? like an error or logs or something

Comment: When I call my webservice with postman, it's good. I believe that the problem is in the front

Comment: Did you configure react proxy, see [configure proxy](https://daveceddia.com/create-react-app-express-backend/) section